# Spring boot with websphere configuration classes not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websphere

I am getting below error when running the app with springboot tomcat. The below error message is repeating continuously. Please help.

> 2015-09-22 03:37:09.477 ERROR 20112 --- [           main]
>   c.i.w.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory  : NMSV0307E: A java: URL name
>   was used, b ut Naming was not configured to handle java: URL names.
>   The likely cause is a user in error attempting to specify a java: URL
>   name in a non- J2EE client or server environment. Throwing
>   ConfigurationException.

**Dependencies**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aredis</groupId>
            <artifactId>aredis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>1.2.16</version> -->

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.joesnmp</groupId>
            <artifactId>joesnmp</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.4</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.ibm.ws.admin</groupId>  
                <artifactId>adminClient</artifactId>  
                <version>8.5.0</version>  
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.ws.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>ibmRuntime</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.websphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>ibmorb</artifactId>
            <version>8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.websphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>ibmorbapi</artifactId>
            <version>8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.websphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>orb</artifactId>
            <version>8.5</version>
        </dependency> 

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <start-class>com.springboot.main.ConfigInitializer</start-class>
        <jersey-version>1.5</jersey-version>
    </properties>
```

Comment: 1.Tomcat has no access to propreatary Ibm classes. 2. Why would you run a Spring Boot app in websphere? Its intended for standalone and cloud deployment. - Remove all Ibm related dependencies.

Comment: My app is a kind of service, which gives service for other applications. So it  will send some websphere related configurations to others apps. So websphere classes are used here. Any idea about above error.?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use JNDI. Why? It isn't enabled by default in embedded Tomcat. Have you enabled it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Spring Boot v1.5.6.RELEASE I had to do this to load WebSphere classes on the classpath:

/src/main/resources/application.properties:

```
spring.jmx.enabled=false
```

/src/main/resources/spring.properties:

```
spring.jndi.ignore=true
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much. Why can't we write the 2nd line in the application.properties file too?